# Force IPv4 address

Tags: raspbian, networking, ethernet, raspbian-jessie, systemd

I upgraded my Raspberry Pi to Jessie, which uses `systemd`. One side-effect is that it connects using IPv6 only and does not have an IPv4 address. How can I force it to get an IPv4 address from the DHCP server?

One ad-hoc solution is the command

```
sudo dhclient -4 -v eth0
```

but this only lasts for the current session.

Comment: None of the answers below worked for me, instead I needed to `sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-client` after using `sudo dhclient -4 -v eth0` to get online.

Comment: Some further context to my previous comment. In my situation the symptoms when running `sudo ifup -v eth0` the call to dhclient was failing and instead showing the usage information.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Raspbian Jessie no longer has a file called `/etc/sysctl.d` -- it's now a ***folder*** of the same name.

According to the read-me file in the same folder, `README.sysctl`, it basically says that any `.conf` file will be read in at boot time and processed. Any legal file name will work, but they suggested `local.conf`, so that's what I used.

I created `/etc/sysctl.d/local.conf` and added the single line from the other answers:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

This appears to work just fine.

Comment: Anything `.d` in `/etc` was never anything but a directory to start with.  I dunno if Joe Platano's answer involves a typo or whether that will actually work, somehow I doubt it (although there seems to be another answer confirming it will).

Comment: For me this served only to kill the ipv6 without creating an ipv4 instead after reboot.

Answer (score 7):

`sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`

append the following lines to turn off ipv6:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

run `sudo sysctl -p` to take effect or just reboot.

Comment: Confirmed working on Raspbian Buster.

Answer (score 3):

In Raspbian Jessie/Jessie Lite, simply edit the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and add the switch to disable ipv6, as follows:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Enter the text:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

Save the file with `Ctrl-O`, `Ctrl-X` and reboot the RPi.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux answer is better ^^^^

Answer (score 2):

you can insert a line into sysctl to disable ipv6.

```
echo net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1 >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

this will work after next reboot.

Comment: It's /etc/sysctl.conf as target file. Be aware that the > will override the entire file!

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way I found to also get an IPv4 address for the interface was changing /etc/network/interfaces: setting the manual to dhcp ... that also gets you an IPv4 address on eth0 ... probably only a hack but haven't found anything better yet either ...

```
    auto eth0
    allow-hotplug eth0
    # iface eth0 inet manual
    iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Raspbian Jessie does not use `dhcp` (unless the user has really fiddled with it) and this would prevent GUI WiFi support from working.

Answer (score 1):

Combining, correcting and adding to the previous answers:

To fix an interface (either eth or wlan) that is showing just an inet6 (IPV6) address and no inet (IPV4) address, you can append a config file to disable inet6 (IPV6) assignment, so that all interfaces are given an inet (IPV4) address. If that config file is then deleted again, interfaces will then be given BOTH an inet (IPV4) and an inet6 (IPV6) address, i.e. a return to the usual default state.

To add the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.d/local.conf
```

and add the single line:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

Save with Ctrl-O, Y, [Return]. Reboot and login again.

```
sudo reboot
```

Check the addresses using

```
ifconfig
```

Remove the config file and reboot:

```
cd /etc/sysctl.d
sudo rm local.conf
sudo reboot
```

Check again with ifconfig:

```
ifconfig
```

See both inet (IPV4) and inet6 (IPV6) addresses for all interfaces:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:53:44:58
          inet addr:192.168.1.228  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::26a5:b629:f948:92c3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:62:b4:7a
          inet addr:192.168.1.229  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::254c:3f61:fdc:bc49/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

And I can once again SSH to my Pi Zero using either eth0 or wlan0, both using either IPV4 or IPV6 address.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded my Raspberry Pi to Stretch and I was unable to have any success with any variation of the `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1` answers.

Manually running `sudo dhclient -4 -v eth0` to get my network/internet connectivity back worked, however as stated by the original poster it does not survive a reboot.

I noticed that `sudo ifup -v eth0` called `dhclient`, but it was failing and instead of functioning correctly, it was showing the usage information for the `dhclient` command.

The workaround appears to be to move away from `dhclient` and instead install `isc-dhcp-client`. Upon reboot my connectivity was automatically available after installing this package.

```
sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-client
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and tried the solution below, this works fine after rebooting my Pi.

```
sudo nano  /etc/sysctl.d/98-rpi.conf
```

type

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

Type Ctrl-X then answer "Y" followed by  to save the file.

```
sudo reboot
```

Now I see my ip4 address on booted screen.