# wlan0 does not get correct IP / gateway on _one particular_ Wi-Fi spot

Tags: networking, wifi, dhcp

**Edit:** I found the possible culprit, see end of question

---

I have started off Jessie, and I need the Pi to be able to connect to various Wi-Fi networks (it will get sent away, so it "just needs to work"). I have had **no issues with two different networks here,** but the one at my place is giving me headaches. For some reason, the Pi connects to the network (WPA) but **does not get assigned a correct IP address, nor gateway.** I have run out of ideas, so I will just dump all the various information I have:

```
$ sudo ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:24:80:03  
          inet addr:169.254.147.2  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a881:c8dd:3d57:eb33/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:363 errors:0 dropped:361 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:41 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:105784 (103.3 KiB)  TX bytes:10547 (10.2 KiB)
```

In comparison, my desktop laptop with Debian gives me correct IP in the 10.0.0.x range:

```
$ sudo ifconfig wlp1s0
wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.18  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::47a5:8d5d:5cb9:285c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:8a:60:a7:09:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 28228503  bytes 35436324026 (33.0 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17543384  bytes 4640642944 (4.3 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So the problem extends to the missing gateway:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

Again, in comparison my working laptop:

```
$ sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.138      0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp1s0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp1s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp1s0
```

The correct gateway is 10.0.0.138.

Here are the network settings of thi Pi:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

And

```
$ cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf 
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU.
# Some interface drivers reset when changing the MTU so disabled by default.
#option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

# A hook script is provided to lookup the hostname if not set by the DHCP
# server, but it should not be run by default.
nohook lookup-hostname

# interface eth0
# 
# static ip_address=192.168.0.11/24
# static routers=192.168.0.1
# static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

(I normally use a static IP on the ethernet for chatting with the laptop; as you can see, I have disabled that here to ensure there is no interference; for the record, eth0 is also not plugged in)

Wi-Fi memory:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf 
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=AT

network={
    ssid="my-network's ssid"
    priority=0
    psk="correct-password"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

And finally, the dhcp attempt:

```
$ sudo dhcpcd -T wlan0
dhcpcd[1213]: version 6.7.1 starting
dhcpcd[1213]: wlan0: IPv6 kernel autoconf disabled
dhcpcd[1213]: DUID 00:01:00:01:1f:77:66:4e:b8:27:eb:24:80:03
dhcpcd[1213]: wlan0: IAID eb:24:80:03
dhcpcd[1213]: wlan0: soliciting a DHCP lease
dhcpcd[1213]: wlan0: soliciting an IPv6 router
dhcpcd[1213]: wlan0: no IPv6 Routers available
^Cdhcpcd[1213]: received signal INT from PID 0, stopping
dhcpcd[1213]: exited
```

And consequently

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by resolvconf
```

So nothing works:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
```

I can do a manual trick, setting the IP with `sudo ifconfig wlan0 10.0.0.66` and `sudo route add default gw 10.0.0.138`, after that I can ping IPs, but DNS is still not working. In any case, it's not a solution, because someone else will boot the Pi in another place and can't do manual IP configuration.

---

**Edit:** After seeing some comments about the `dhcpcd -T`, I thought that IP v6 might be the problem. I found [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23884/force-ipv4-address); and *hurray*, this makes the system work:

```
sudo dhclient -4 -v wlan0
```

Now my questions are:

1. What would be the correct way to make this permanent? I tried create this `/etc/sysctl.d/local.conf` as suggested, but it doesn't have any effect, after a reboot I have to run the above `dhclient` command again.
2. Do I create a new possible problem for other Wi-Fi hot spots? In other words, can this setting lead to a situation where my system doesn't connect to a Wi-Fi network that it previously hadn't had any issues with?

Comment: And your question is??

Comment: @Milliways 1. Any ideas what the actual problem is here? 2. Should I use this 'dhclient -v' approach? If so, how do I make it permanent, and do I create a risk for other wi-fi routers if force ip v4?