# WorldTimeApi client_ip

Tags: python-3, micropython

I am trying to use World Time Api to get the ip address assigned by my ISP.  In Micro Python on an RPi Pico W `my_ip = json["client_ip"]` returns an ipv4 address and in Python3 on a RPi 4B it returns an ipv6 address.  I would like to get the ipv4 version in both cases. How do I get the ipv4 address in Python3 on a RPi 4B using Python3?

Comment: Try this https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23884/force-ipv4-address

Comment: Steve, thanks for the response. Since I have already used MQTT to send messages between devices, I decided to send the IPv4 using MQTT rather than delve into your link.